# Is there any way to easily merge two Pandora stations into a single station?

Tags: pandora

I have two stations that I'd like to merge.  I essentially want all the seed, thumbed up, and thumbed down songs from one station to be added to the other.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible. This was asked in [Pandora support forum](http://getsatisfaction.com/pandora/topics/merge_stations) a year ago and the official response was:

> Another cool idea, Sheldon. Thanks! We
>   appreciate your 10 cents.
>
> For now, you can always **QuickMix** any
>   of your stations together.
>
> :) Lucia

The latest message on this page is 19 days old and it seems they still haven't added this feature. So your best bet would be using QuickMix which can temporarily merge two stations.

> **[QuickMix](http://blog.pandora.com/faq/contents/478.html)** is a feature designed to allow you to listen to
>   more than one of your stations at
>   once. For those who'd like to merge or
>   combine two stations, QuickMix can
>   *temporarily* give you that effect.

Comment: QuickMix is now called Shuffle. Also, they still haven't added this feature.

Comment: Quick mix just plays all stations, I dont feel like going to sleep and having rock wake me from a dead sleep. I wonder why they dont do "Mix Selected Stations"

Comment: I was just wondering this myself... personally, I'd like it if I could "add variety" to a station with other "genre" stations. Combine 80s, 90s, 00s Country Music stations as seeds into my Gangster Rap station.